# Datagrid doesn't render all data

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have the code like this:

```
const [param, setParam] = useState({
    page: 1,
    pageSize: 10,
  });
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const t = await fetcherGetListProduct(
          param.page,
          param.pageSize,
          false
        );
        setTotalRowCount(t.total);
        setData(t.data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching data:", error);
      }
    };

    fetchData();
}, [param]);
const handlePageChange = (value) => {
    setParam({ page: value.page, pageSize: value.pageSize });
};

<DataGrid
   rows={data || []}
   columns={columns2}
   components={{ Toolbar: GridToolbar }}
   initialState={{
   pagination: {
       paginationModel: { pageSize: 10, page: 1 },
     },
   }}
   pageSizeOptions={[5, 10, 25]}
   rowCount={totalRowCount}
   onPaginationModelChange={handlePageChange}
/>
```

Each time I modify the page or pageSize, it call API and return the arr :
But only first element of the array show on the Datagrid. (Not the first page).
Example page 2 have 5 elements but it only show 1.
How can I fix it?

I want it show all data of another page.

Comment: is your api returning the desired data?

Comment: @HarshitT yes. I have 8 products with pageSize = 5, page 1 ==> it rendered the right data in the data grid but when I move to page=2 --> the API returns arr 3  but it only shows 1 data in the data grid